# Problems on calling Microsoft Access with command line from Windows batch file

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm trying to write a Windows batch file to call a **Microsoft Access** application and pass a command to the **Access** program. That's fairly easy using **Access**'s `/cmd` switch and the VBA `Command()` function – as long as the parameters don't contain special characters, like double quotes or spaces. I also have a requirement that if the batch file isn't called with any parameters, it will prompt the user for parameters for the command.

For example, here's a call to `test_cmd` with parameters:

```
test_cmd Command 1234 type true region "Steve's Command Test" "Steve's testing notes that are very, very long."
```

If the user runs `test_cmd` without any parameters, the user should be able to do this:

```
test_cmd
Syntax is test_cmd command ["command_parm_1" ["command_parm_2"]...]
Enter the command to run (pressing Enter will exit):  Command 1234 type true region "Steve's Command Test" "Steve's testing notes that are very, very long."
```

So that leads to three problems:

1. With the full command line version, the double quotes are removed and not passed to Access. This means that I can't easily tell where one parameter ends and the next one starts. I solved this by inserting my own delimiters ("{#" in the batch file below) in front of %2-%9. That actually works if my VBA code uses the `Split` function to split on the delimiter, but it's kind of ugly.
2. With the prompted version, double quotes cause errors saying the next token after the first double quote was not expected. Searching the world wide web led me to command `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, but then the double quotes are removed when the `Command()` function gets the command line.
3. Even after getting #1 working with the delimiter and using single quotes in the prompted version in #2, the command line **Access** processes often gets truncated.

I realize that this is a bit hard to follow, so I'm including the batch file and a simple **Access** function (called by an `AutoExec` macro) that illustrates the problem.

NOTE: The **Access** module tries both the `Command()` **Access** function and the Win32 `GetCommandLine` function, and both often get truncated at the same place as mentioned in #3 above.

**TEST_CMD.BAT**

```
@echo off

rem Set default environment variables
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET AppName=%0

Set AppCommand=%1
IF "%AppCommand%" == "" GOTO HELP

:EXECUTE
ECHO Running %AppName% with command line !AppCommand! %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
ECHO Command = "!AppCommand!" Parameters (in brackets) = [%~2][%~3][%~4][%~5][%~6][%~7][%~8][%~9]

REM Prefix the parameters with "{#" to allow the app to see where the parameters begin (the double quotes are stripped by the DOS command processor)
REM Because of this, only eight parameters may be passed to the app!
"Test_Cmd.accdb" /cmd !AppCommand! {#%2{#%3{#%4{#%5{#%6{#%7{#%8{#%9

ECHO EXECUTION COMPLETE
GOTO EXIT

:PROMPT
SET /P AppCommand="Enter the command to run (pressing Enter will exit):  "
ECHO You entered !AppCommand!
IF "!AppCommand!" == "" GOTO EXIT
GOTO EXECUTE

:HELP
ECHO Syntax is %AppName% command ["command_parm_1" ["command_parm_2"]...]
GOTO PROMPT

REM Exit the batch file
:EXIT

REM Restore environment variables
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

**CommandLineTest VBA Module**

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Note: Declaration is overloaded with LONG!
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
#End If

' Application startup code
' Called by AutoExec macro via RunCode (so this MUST be a function, not a subroutine!)
Function TestCommandLine()
    Dim strCommandLine As String
    Dim strGetCommandLine As String
    Dim bExit As Boolean
    
    ' Get the /cmd arguments from Access
    strCommandLine = Trim(Command())
    strGetCommandLine = Trim(GetCommandLine)

    ' NOTE:  The following MsgBox call shows what parameters Access thinks were passed
    Call MsgBox("Command() Len(" & Len(strCommandLine) & ") = " & strCommandLine & vbCrLf & _
                            "GetCommandLineA() Len (" & Len(strGetCommandLine) & ") = " & strGetCommandLine, _
                            vbOKOnly, "Testing")
    bExit = (vbYes = MsgBox("Do you want to exit?", vbYesNo, "Exit"))
    
    If bExit Then Application.Quit
End Function ' TestCommandLine

Function GetCommandLine() As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    #If Win64 Then
    Dim lngPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
    Dim lngPtr As Long
    #End If
    Dim StringLength As Long
    
    ' Get the pointer to the commandline string
    lngPtr = GetCommandLineL

    ' Get the length of the string (not including the terminating null character)
    StringLength = lstrlenL(lngPtr)

    ' Initialize our string so it has enough characters including the null character
    strReturn = String$(StringLength + 1, 0)

    ' Copy the string we have a pointer to into our new string:
    lstrcpyL strReturn, lngPtr

    ' Strip off the null character at the end
    GetCommandLine = Left$(strReturn, StringLength)
End Function ' GetCommandLine
```

Is there a simple way to handle this with longer command lines?

Comment: Reason for that many params? What about using powershell, where you can access the application object and pass params to a property or sth. like that? Btw, your complier constant could be `VBA7` instead of `WIN64`as all declaration are x86/x64 compatible as long as you use `LongPtr`See [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit)

Comment: why not double the quotes? `"Test_Cmd.accdb" /cmd !AppCommand! "%2" "%3" "%4 "%5 "%6" "%7" "%8" "%9"`

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thanks for pointing out that GetCommandLine should use VBA7.  I copied that code from Web to see if it would fix the problem of double quotes disappearing.

As for using PowerShell, I don't know PowerShell, so there's that.  I presume that I could use a PowerShell script, but the Batch file above is supposed to be used by other users who may want to see how to call my access application via a Batch file.

As for the number of parameters, I'm not sure why that matters, but it's the maximum number of items a user would fill in on one of the forms I'm creating an API for.

Comment: @Gerhard I'm not surrounding the Batch file parameters with double quotes because the last parameter could contain double quotes.  I also believe that I tried that early on in the process, but it didn't work; the Command() function still didn't get the quotes.

However, I just tried it, and with the text shown at the top of my post, I got the error "'Command' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Sorry, but that won't change anything, except making more sense as if you use `WIN64` compller constant, you should declare pointers/handles as `LongLong`instead of `LongPtr` to show you understood what you do. In the end `LongPtr`is converted to `LongLong`on Office64, but its purpose is to create an universal data-type for pointers/handles, independent of app bitness. So your source of API declarations may contain flaws (as it shows lack of understanding). A trustworthy source is [Windows API Viewer for MS Excel](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm).

Comment: In Powershell you can access Ms Office Application objects, like you can do from VBA. (e.g open Excel sheets from Access and manipulate them). Why should a user use a batch file to enter data, instead of using forms that are designed for that?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher As I mentioned, I'm trying to create an API to allow users to use the application from Batch files/PowerShell scripts without have to manually enter data in forms.  Why?  Because I have a user requirement to do so.  A form is easy to use if you're entering a few data items, but if you want to enter dozens, using a script that calls an API may make more sense.  There's a reason command line utilities still exist in this world of GUIs.  :-D

As for PowerShell, will that help handle my issue with double quotes?